# Figure out exactly what Rejuicer is doing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, minify, bundling-and-minification

I need some help with Rejuicer. I just inherited a C# webapplication that uses it and I cannot figure out what exactly is going on.

in the global.asmx.cs under Application_Start we are

`OnRequest.ForJs("~/Combined-{0}.js")
                .Combine
               .FilesIn("~/js-survey/")
               .Matching("*.js")
               .Configure();`

I believe this is combining all the *.js in the js-survey/ folder into a single js called Combined-Uniquename.js.
Is this combining the file on the server?

Then in the Master Page it is using
               `"<%# Rejuiced.JsFor("~/Combined-{0}.js") %>"`

is this retrieving the file from the server?

How can I test these?

s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this combining the file on the server?

It is dynamically combining the JavaScript files on app startup and storing them in memory. When a request is done to `~/Combined-HASH.js`, Rejuicer handles the request and serves the combined files from memory. This is handled by [RejuicerModule](https://github.com/skroonenburg/Rejuicer/blob/master/Source/Rejuicer/Rejuicer/Engine/RejuicerModule.cs).

The `{0}` is replaced by a hash of the file. It ensures that when any of the files are changed, the cache is invalidated (since the "file name" will be different). `Rejuiced.JsFor` renders a `<script>` tag with the correct URL including the hash.

Take a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/skroonenburg/Rejuicer/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-Documentation) and [website](http://web.archive.org/web/20140102222756/http://rejuice.me/) (web.archive.org mirror, the site no longer exists) for more information.